# How To Replace a Double Set of Quotation Marks with a Single set of Quotation Marks

Tags: c#, regex, xml, invalid-characters

I am parsing some manifest files and need to sanitize them before I can load them as XML. So, these files are **invalid XML files**.

Consider the following snippet:

```
<assemblyIdentity name=""Microsoft.Windows.Shell.DevicePairingFolder"" processorArchitecture=""amd64"" version=""5.1.0.0"" type="win32" />
```

There are several instances of double quotes, `""`, that I want to replace with single occurrences, `"`.

Essentially, the example would be transformed to

```
<assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Windows.Shell.DevicePairingFolder" processorArchitecture="amd64" version="5.1.0.0" type="win32" />
```

I presume a regex would be the best approach here, however, it is not my strong point.

The following should be noted:

- The manifest is a multiline string (essentially just an XML document)
- Something like `processorArchitecture=""` is valid in the document hence why a simple `string.Replace` call is not appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways:

1. String replace

```
var newString = s.Replace("\"\"", "\"");
```

2. Regex.

```
string checkStringForDoubleQuotes = @"""";
string newString  = Regex.Replace(s, checkStringForDoubleQuotes , @""");
```

After update:

Your regex is this https://regex101.com/r/xZUtUf/1/

```
""(?=\w)|(?<=\w)""
```

```
string s = "test=\"\" test2=\"\"assdasad\"\"";
string checkStringForDoubleQuotes = "\"\"(?=\\w)|(?<=\\w)\"\"";
string newString  = Regex.Replace(s, checkStringForDoubleQuotes , "\"");
Console.WriteLine(newString);
// test="" test2="assdasad"
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/FmWXUa

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned (with context to the example provided) that something like `processorArchitecture=""` is valid in said manifest and I wouldn't want to change this to `processorArchitecture="` - I will edit the post to reflect this

Comment: Check the updated code.

Comment: Sorry for the last update, I c/p the solution incorrectly. Check the latest version for a working example.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
(\w+=)""(.*?)""(?=\s+\w+=|$)
```

Replace with `$1"$2"`. See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/JTBh55/1).

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \w+                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or
                             more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    =                        '='
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ""                       '""'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ""                       '""'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \w+                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or
                             more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    =                        '='
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $                        before an optional \n, and the end of
                             the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

[C# example](https://tio.run/##ZVFNT8MwDL33V0TVDi2DsPF1GWUgGBKHSYghcdklS80WKU2ifKytYL@9JOmEBvMhcez3HPuZmjMqNXSdM0ys0aI1FqpJcvjC79BY/AZrx4meNUqDMUwKM0kS5VacUUQ5MQbNGlIpDslXgrztU8YS66@tZCWaEyayPGZ7TDBjdfhKEWtBC1Sg@zRb1sMiT71l@GTaO9NiaYYh/j3I08l/tnErY5l11vcVSwzGaTq48MQjKBPK2Yi59U1DteLtSwnCs1skSAVF@G7OqJZGflr8wUQpa4MXG@AcP8GWUXglLJR6lrwEHeBIaUm9KlI/aLphFqh1uq9EqvLmKmK2oINsMXqNx3iERzFuWxWgNROXvmF0fnfQ86/j1YcG6XgWSEDdR7K9bPnRmH5Jjoc5I8dvT3FCIYvTn/7R64D76LcqOeAP7WfI@hL79C7Zdd0P):

```cs
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"(\w+=)""""(.*?)""""(?=\s+\w+=|$)";
        string substitution = @"$1""$2""";
        string input = @"<assemblyIdentity name=""""Microsoft.Windows.Shell.DevicePairingFolder"""" processorArchitecture=""""amd64"""" version=""""5.1.0.0"""" type=""win32"" />";
        
        Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
        string result = regex.Replace(input, substitution);
        Console.Write(result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the hex escape for quotes as `\x22` to make it easier to work with. This will replace each individual consecutive `""` to `"`.

```
 Regex.Replace(data, @"(\x22\x22)", "\x22")
```